# Xpath: how to get a parent node of my selected node?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a problem to get the parent node of my selected node.
I'm using the query: / / t [@ lemma = "de"] .
But I would like to get the element  that  is contained.
I do not understand much about xpath.
Now I'm using two queries to try to solve the problem, but I think it is not necessary.
My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <corpus> 
        <body>
            <s id="s16" ref="16" source="Running text" forest="1" text="DECLARARAL A ExtinÃ§Ã£o da Punibilidade do RÃ©u, Em RazÃ£o da PrescriÃ§Ã£o da PretensÃ£o Punitiva, Fulcro Em os ARTIGOS 107, Inciso IV, Combinado Com O ARTIGO 109, Inciso VI (RedaÃ§Ã£o Anterior Ã Lei NÂº.">
                <graph root="s16_500">
                    <terminals>
                        <t id="s16_1" word="DECLARARAL" lemma="DECLARARAL" pos="prop" morph="--" extra="cjt-head cjt-head-X" />
                        <t id="s16_2" word="A" lemma="o" pos="art" morph="F S" extra="artd" />
                        <t id="s16_3" word="ExtinÃ§Ã£o" lemma="ExtinÃ§Ã£o" pos="prop" morph="--" extra="cjt-X" />
                        <t id="s16_4" word="de" lemma="de" pos="prp" morph="--" extra="sam-" />
                        <t id="s16_5" word="a" lemma="o" pos="art" morph="F S" extra="-sam artd" />
                        <t id="s16_6" word="Punibilidade" lemma="punibilidade" pos="n" morph="F S" extra="prop percep-f" />
                        <t id="s16_7" word="de" lemma="de" pos="prp" morph="--" extra="sam-" />
                        <t id="s16_8" word="o" lemma="o" pos="art" morph="M S" extra="-sam artd" />
                        <t id="s16_9" word="RÃ©u" lemma="rÃ©u" pos="n" morph="M S" extra="prop H" />
                        <t id="s16_10" word="," lemma="--" pos="pu" morph="--" extra="--" />
                        <t id="s16_11" word="Em_RazÃ£o" lemma="Em_RazÃ£o" pos="prop" morph="--" extra="cjt-X" />
                        <t id="s16_12" word="de" lemma="de" pos="prp" morph="--" extra="sam-" />
                        <t id="s16_13" word="a" lemma="o" pos="art" morph="F S" extra="-sam artd" />
                        <t id="s16_14" word="PrescriÃ§Ã£o" lemma="prescriÃ§Ã£o" pos="n" morph="F S" extra="prop conv" />
                        <t id="s16_15" word="de" lemma="de" pos="prp" morph="--" extra="sam-" />
                        <t id="s16_16" word="a" lemma="o" pos="art" morph="F S" extra="-sam artd" />
                        <t id="s16_17" word="PretensÃ£o_Punitiva" lemma="PretensÃ£o_Punitiva" pos="prop" morph="--" extra="--" />
                        <t id="s16_18" word="," lemma="--" pos="pu" morph="--" extra="--" />
                        <t id="s16_19" word="Fulcro" lemma="fulcro" pos="n" morph="M S" extra="cjt-X part-build Labs" />
                        <t id="s16_20" word="Em" lemma="em" pos="prp" morph="--" extra="sam-" />
                        <t id="s16_21" word="os" lemma="o" pos="art" morph="M P" extra="artd -sam" />
                        <t id="s16_22" word="ARTIGOS_107" lemma="ARTIGOS_107" pos="prop" morph="--" extra="--" />
                        <t id="s16_23" word="," lemma="--" pos="pu" morph="--" extra="--" />
                        <t id="s16_24" word="Inciso_IV" lemma="Inciso_IV" pos="prop" morph="--" extra="cjt-X" />
                        <t id="s16_25" word="," lemma="--" pos="pu" morph="--" extra="--" />
                        <t id="s16_26" word="Combinado_Com" lemma="Combinado_Com" pos="prop" morph="--" extra="cjt-X" />
                        <t id="s16_27" word="O" lemma="o" pos="art" morph="M S" extra="artd" />
                        <t id="s16_28" word="ARTIGO_109" lemma="ARTIGO_109" pos="prop" morph="--" extra="cjt-X" />
                        <t id="s16_29" word="," lemma="--" pos="pu" morph="--" extra="--" />
                        <t id="s16_30" word="Inciso_VI" lemma="Inciso_VI" pos="prop" morph="--" extra="cjt-X" />
                        <t id="s16_31" word="(" lemma="--" pos="pu" morph="--" extra="--" />
                        <t id="s16_32" word="RedaÃ§Ã£o_Anterior_Ã_Lei_NÂº" lemma="RedaÃ§Ã£o_Anterior_Ã_Lei_NÂº" pos="prop" morph="--" extra="cjt-X" />
                        <t id="s16_33" word="." lemma="--" pos="pu" morph="--" extra="--" />
                    </terminals>

                    <nonterminals>
                        <nt id="s16_500" cat="s">
                            <edge label="X" idref="s16_501" />
                        </nt>
                        <nt id="s16_501" cat="par">
                            <edge label="CJT" idref="s16_1" />
                            <edge label="CJT" idref="s16_502" />
                            <edge label="PU" idref="s16_10" />
                            <edge label="CJT" idref="s16_507" />
                            <edge label="PU" idref="s16_18" />
                            <edge label="CJT" idref="s16_512" />
                            <edge label="PU" idref="s16_23" />
                            <edge label="CJT" idref="s16_24" />
                            <edge label="PU" idref="s16_25" />
                            <edge label="CJT" idref="s16_26" />
                            <edge label="CJT" idref="s16_515" />
                            <edge label="PU" idref="s16_29" />
                            <edge label="CJT" idref="s16_30" />
                            <edge label="PU" idref="s16_31" />
                            <edge label="CJT" idref="s16_32" />
                            <edge label="PU" idref="s16_33" />
                        </nt>
                        <nt id="s16_502" cat="np">
                            <edge label="DN" idref="s16_2" />
                            <edge label="H" idref="s16_3" />
                            <edge label="DN" idref="s16_503" />
                        </nt>
                        <nt id="s16_503" cat="pp">
                            <edge label="H" idref="s16_4" />
                            <edge label="DP" idref="s16_504" />
                        </nt>
                        <nt id="s16_504" cat="np">
                            <edge label="DN" idref="s16_5" />
                            <edge label="H" idref="s16_6" />
                            <edge label="DN" idref="s16_505" />
                        </nt>
                        <nt id="s16_505" cat="pp">
                            <edge label="H" idref="s16_7" />
                            <edge label="DP" idref="s16_506" />
                        </nt>
                        <nt id="s16_506" cat="np">
                            <edge label="DN" idref="s16_8" />
                            <edge label="H" idref="s16_9" />
                        </nt>
                        <nt id="s16_507" cat="np">
                            <edge label="H" idref="s16_11" />
                            <edge label="DN" idref="s16_508" />
                        </nt>
                        <nt id="s16_508" cat="pp">
                            <edge label="H" idref="s16_12" />
                            <edge label="DP" idref="s16_509" />
                        </nt>
                        <nt id="s16_509" cat="np">
                            <edge label="DN" idref="s16_13" />
                            <edge label="H" idref="s16_14" />
                            <edge label="DN" idref="s16_510" />
                        </nt>
                        <nt id="s16_510" cat="pp">
                            <edge label="H" idref="s16_15" />
                            <edge label="DP" idref="s16_511" />
                        </nt>
                        <nt id="s16_511" cat="np">
                            <edge label="DN" idref="s16_16" />
                            <edge label="H" idref="s16_17" />
                        </nt>
                        <nt id="s16_512" cat="np">
                            <edge label="H" idref="s16_19" />
                            <edge label="DN" idref="s16_513" />
                        </nt>
                        <nt id="s16_513" cat="pp">
                            <edge label="H" idref="s16_20" />
                            <edge label="DP" idref="s16_514" />
                        </nt>
                        <nt id="s16_514" cat="np">
                            <edge label="DN" idref="s16_21" />
                            <edge label="H" idref="s16_22" />
                        </nt>
                        <nt id="s16_515" cat="np">
                            <edge label="DN" idref="s16_27" />
                            <edge label="H" idref="s16_28" />
                        </nt>
                    </nonterminals>
                </graph> 
            </s>
        </body>
    </corpus>
</xml>
```

can someone help me?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to select? The `<terminals>` element? Or are you talking about traversing the id/idref links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

> all I need is the tag `<s>` under the conditions of `t[@lemma = 'de']`

In that case what you need is something like

```
//s[graph/terminals/t/@lemma = 'de']
```

An = comparison where one side is a node set succeeds if *any* of the nodes in the set has the required value.

Comment: Ian, there is only one `s` element in the provided XML document, so the OP's comment hardly makes sense...

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev in this specific sample, yes, but I took it to be representative of a bigger document - I work in computational linguistics so I realise that a corpus of one document which in turn has one sentence isn't going to be a full example...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent node like this :

```
//t[@lemma="de"]/..
```

It's like Unix shell :

```
cd ..
```

stands for *change dir for parent dir*

Comment: The return of xpath: / / t [@ lemma = "of"] / .. Not what I wanted, I would like to get the tag <s> , but the return of this xpath is <terminals>

Comment: And the xpath: //*[t/@lemma="de"] is very similar to what I want, but do not want to return the tag <root>, all I need is the tag <s> under the conditions of t[@lemma="de"]

Comment: s is not the parent of the t element, it is the grandparent. To get the s element, use `//s[terminals/t/@lemma='de']`.